# After git reset <commitid> how to push to master?

Tags: git

I made a series of mistakes and I want to revert 4 commits back.  I did this:

```
git reset <commitId>
```

This caused me to have a number of changes not staged for commit, and a number of untracked files.

The untracked files are the new files for the unwanted commits and I manually removed the files using

```
rm <file>
```

I then ran the project and everything is to my liking.

I now think I should do a

```
git commit -m 'reverting back to XXXXX' 
git push
```

Does this sound about right?  Just want to be sure I am doing this right.

Edit: I think as others of told me, this doesn't quite make sense.  I believe I had actually confused reset versus revert.  I checked the correct answer for my situation.  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds right. I think you're okay. I would just add a `--hard` option on your reset option to guarantee that the commit history and the working directory would match the chosen to commit and remove anything after this snapshot.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you had already pushed the commits you're about to "forget" with this `reset`, the remote will refuse your `push` unless you're using `--force-with-lease` or `--force`.

Comment: You only say that you removed the untracked files, but you do not say that you reverted the unstaged changes. This does not sound right. Also, at the point where your description states that a commit is made, there should not be anything to commit. On top of that, when you undo changes using `git reset`, making a commit with the message "reverting back to xxxx" does not sound correct, either; instead, with `git reset` you pretend that the incorrect commits never existed and that there is nothing to revert.

Comment: j6t - I think you are right.  I am not sure whats up with the state of my repo.  It could be that I did a revert instead of a reset?  Let me try again with a reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a reset you normally don't have to actually do any commits since what it does is to reset the branch to point to an old commit.

If you want to do a true reset without re-committing anything you should do a `git reset <old-commit> --hard`

Afterwards you need to do a force push. `git push --force-with-lease`.
the `with-lease` part makes the force push fail if somebody else have made changes to the branch.
Pushing with force basically changes the remote branch location without checking that the new location is a descendant of its current location.

Comment: Hi.  OP here.  I think this is what I want.  Let me try that again.  Question though, just to clarify, lets say I have this:
[commit 1=bad code]
[commit 2=bad code]
[commit 3=this is what I want]
[commit 4=this is too far back]

Then I want to reset to commit 3 right?  so git reset <commit 3> --hard

Comment: @SpecialEd yes, assuming you mean the lower numbered commits are the newest commits.